# SPF record for MX records?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I am maintaining the DNS records of a domain which was set up by someone else.

I have following RRs (visible in an webinterface):

```
example.com A 1.2.3.4
example.com MX 10:mail.example.com
example.com TXT "v=spf1 mx ip4:1.2.3.4 -all"

mail.example.com A 1.2.3.4
mail.example.com TXT "v=spf1 include:example.com"
```

Is it correct that I can remove the SPF TXT record of mail.example.com ? As far as I know, it is not necessary. (Assuming that eMails are sent from xxx@example.com , and never from xxx@mail.example.com )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the TXT record for `mail.example.com`.

Comment: Consider using TXT "v=spf1 -all" rather then not having one completely.